# Failed review audit by commenting on a broad and vague question

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823832/generating-3d-map-video-in-android-using-location-data was shown to me in the review queue as an audit. My action was to post a comment asking if the user had tried anything.

> Have you tried anything so far?

However, I failed this audit.

Surprisingly the question has a significant amount of upvotes, but I still think (even if it asks for directions and not code), that it is too vague. Isn't such a question supposed to be off topic as "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking"?

Am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: It is considered good because it has gathered 11 upvotes.

Comment: I guess the upvotes were because of the bounty.

Comment: @gnat I think it is very close to duplicate (and I will vote for it). However here, I am reporting another case of not so good audit.

Comment: Questions that have previously had bounties placed on them should not be eligible for audits, but it sounds like that might have a glitch in it at present. These are known problematic cases for audits.

Comment: @BradLarson Would it be better to rephrase this question in order to be more like a bug / feature request, in order to point that `Questions that have previously had bounties placed on them should not be eligible for audits` as you said. Or we can open a new question for this.

Comment: @Athafoud - I hear it's being looked into, because you aren't the first person to hit this in the last few weeks. If you still feel like filing this as a bug report, you can, but it is being checked.

Comment: Looks like this check was omitted from the First Posts and Low Quality queues. The latter doesn't matter for Stack Overflow, but the former does; will look at getting this fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this question is definitely too broad for Stack Overflow. As can be seen from the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39823832/revisions), it had a bounty put on it, so that's probably why it has attracted so many upvotes. Thanks to the [Meta-effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect), it is now on its way to being downvoted and/or closed.

Note that you can fail 'negative' audits by just leaving a comment - if the question is really off-topic, you need to flag it for closure as well.

Comment: Regarding your **Note**, I am aware of this, however in some cases that there is space for improvement (as in this question), I like to give the user the chance to correct the question and add the missing parts.

Comment: @Athafoud It's important for questions that aren't appropriate to be closed *as soon as possible*.  **That is the primary reason the review queues exist in the first place**.  If you see questions that merit closure, you should be voting to close them.  While deciding to take the extra time to provide personalized feedback is great if you want to do so, that should be *in addition* to voting to close, not *instead* of voting to close.  To not is to not be reviewing properly.

Comment: Well it looks like the meta-effect train wrecked itself all over that post