# Should I have failed this review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14195184). I flagged it as Off Topic -> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")... Not a big deal that I failed, but I am curious about this review audit.

From my view (without checking the edit history) it looked like either we weren't given enough information in the question to solve it, or it was just a code dump asking us to find out what was wrong with it.

I see that in the edit history, before the condition it was in when I reviewed it, it was an arguably better question that could be clearly answered (*On topic*). However, without the context of the earlier versions of the question, I didn't think it could be easily answered in it's present state.

Was I wrong? Am I supposed to go to the question and check the edit history?

Comment: It looks like a bounty issue [again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336823/2285236)

Comment: @ayhan Not really related to the bounty.  It appears that the question was simply a good question and the OP vandalized it (or at least turned it from a good question to a bad one?) with his recent edit.

Comment: @Servy - Even so, bountied questions should be off-limits from being audit cases and the system isn't processing that right. I rolled it back to the way it was as the bounty was issued, but it has changed shape three or four times, so it's a mess. It wouldn't have been an audit case before the bounty, and shouldn't have been eligible afterward.